# Idiomatic way to enforce single page app being used in one tab only

Tags: javascript, web-storage

I created let say quite complex application that uses IndexedDb heavily. After some investigation I found that this was truly a pain to accomplish. Only way I can think of is utilizing Web Storage (cross tab communication) to warn user that:

a) he can't open another tab when another one is open

b) if he continues the old tab will be closed

but it is really ugly to bother user with it. The alternatives are :

1. allowing multiple tabs and coordinate and synchronize stuff using a Web Storage or SharedWorker via shared context (far future), which means to literally program the multitab compliance (I don't have the resources to do so, imho it'd be quite hairy anyway)
2. developing it as a chrome app, like Postman or [this test editor](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/text-editor)

Are there any other alternatives? How do you guys do it? I feel like the app complexity would grow too much if I don't enforce the "one tab only" way. It is not easy to secure every aspect of your app to work in multiple tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable in the sessionStorage and check every time if this variable is present. If so its the second tab and you can react.

To signal the first tab that a second tab has been opend you can use the [storage-Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage). 
Just listen to that event in the first tab and write something on page load in the second tab. At this point the event get fired in the first Tab and you can react.

Comment: That's basically the first and third point I mentioned in my question. That increases the app complexity, there is too much stuff to synchronize and coordinate.

Comment: All you have to do is to check against the variable and let your application die at this point. No complexity here. You cant pretend the user from opening another tab

Comment: You just described the technical solution of the third point. It is trivial to do so, but obviously extremely ugly to bother user with it. Would your mom understand what is even happening? She would close entire browser because of it :-) I didn't ask here to explain how these 3 points would be done, I know that. I was asking for alternatives.

Comment: you could instead show a message that briefly explain that they have to close the tab and use the old one but I admit my Mother deosnt event know what a "tab" is. On the other hand she isnt able to open a link in a new Tab either :P

Comment: Well I guess the third point is just inevitable, so sad, I can't really think of anything else than this ugly hackery...